# Get single-line json from aws cli

Tags: node.js, json, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have this command:

```
aws ec2 describe-regions --output=json
```

the output looks like:

```
{
    "Regions": [
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com", 
            "RegionName": "eu-north-1"
        }, 
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com", 
            "RegionName": "ap-northeast-2"
        }, 
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", 
            "RegionName": "us-west-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

that's not really usable by machine though, I am looking for output on a single-line like so:

```
{"Regions":[{"Endpoint":"ec2.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com","RegionName":"eu-north-1"},{"Endpoint":"ec2.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com","RegionName":"ap-northeast-2"},{"Endpoint":"ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com","RegionName":"us-west-2"}]}
```

is there some command with the aws-cli that gives me machine-readable JSON? Something like:

```
aws ec2 describe-regions --output='json-for-machines'
```

?

Comment: whys that not readable?

Comment: I have a streaming-parser than splits the json by newline character, if there are newlines in the json string my parser won't work ... newline delimited json parsers are common so..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use jq to compact it like so.

```
aws ec2 describe-regions --output=json| jq -c
```

output becomes

```
{"Regions":[{"Endpoint":"ec2.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com","RegionName":"eu-north-1"},{"Endpoint":"ec2.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com","RegionName":"ap-northeast-2"},{"Endpoint":"ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com","RegionName":"us-west-2"}]}
```

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Answer (score 2):

[jq answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56014467/328565) is a good choice. If you don't have `jq` but have `python`:

```
aws ec2 describe-regions --output=json | python -c 'import json, sys; json.dump(json.load(sys.stdin), sys.stdout)'
```

If you don't have `jq` but have `node`:

```
aws ec2 describe-regions --output=json | node -e 'console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(require("fs").readFileSync(0, "utf8"))))'
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using windows cmd:

```
aws ec2 describe-regions  --output json | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

- ConvertFrom-Json: converts it to manageable object
- ConvertTo-Json -Compress: gets rid of newlines

Comment: I can't verify this works, but hopefully someone will eventually

Comment: $output  = -join $output | ConvertFrom-Json

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you're using node.js to parse a json-stream, you can use:

https://github.com/ORESoftware/json-parser

```
const k = cp.spawn('bash');

k.stdin.end(`
   aws ec2 describe-instances --output=json --region='us-west-2'; echo '∆';
   aws ec2 describe-instances --output=json --region='us-west-1'; echo '∆';
   aws ec2 describe-instances --output=json --region='us-east-1'; echo '∆';
`);

k.stdout.pipe(new JSONParser({delimiter:'∆'}).on('data', d => {
    // { Reservations: [{}] }
});
```

just use some weird unicode character delimiter and should be no worse than using newlines to delimit, eg:

```
const delimiter = 'ƒ∆ø';
```